# in a .htaccess file, how do you correct multiple features of a url without redirecting each time?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Let's say I want people coming to my website at website.com/something to be redirected to: https://www.website.com/something/

I know how to write rules to fix this (such as forcing www and a trailing slash), but only so that the url is corrected once at a time.  i.e.

website.com/something
-> www.website.com/something
-> https://www.website.com/something
-> https://www.website.com/something/

Is there a way to fix everything in one go (if it is not present in the url) to avoid all the redirects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ https://www.website.com/$1/ [NE,L,R]
```

#### Explanation:

There are 3 conditions with `[OR]`. That means if any of following conditions are true:

1. IF HTTPS is off `OR`
2. IF `REQUEST_URI` doesn't have trailing slash `OR`
3. IF `HTTP_HOST` variable isn't starting with `www`

**then do the redirect.**

**PS:** `^(.+?)/?$` captures `REQUEST_URI` without the last the trailing slash in `$1`.

Comment: Could you briefly explain what this does?

Comment: Yes sure added explanation.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I'm just confused about one thing.  The regex you use for no trailing slash doesn't make sense to me: ^(.+?)/?$`

Comment: That regex can be tested in any online regex tester. It basically make talking slash optional and captures text without matching last slash.

Comment: The regex seems to match everything (including the trailing slash)...also, did you mean to have the last ` character there?